# Having troubles sharing sessions between subdomains in express

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I'm trying to share a session between multiple subdomains (under the same root domain), so user can login in dashboard.example.com, and when viewing x.example.com, he will be identified on backend.

I'm using express with express-session and passport.js and my backend server is sitting behind NGINX server. I went through all topics I could find here, but none of them helped me fix the issue.

Here is my express-session configuration:

```
{
  store: redisStore,
  secret: 'secret',
  name: 'app.sid',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  proxy: true,
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    expires: Date.now() + parseInt(process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRATION_MS, 10),
    maxAge: parseInt(process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRATION_MS, 10),
    httpOnly: true,
    domain: '.example.com'
  }
}
```

I read on some threads here I should set response headers as well:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept')
  next()
})
```

When logging into the app through dashboard.example.com, the session is created fine, and on browser I see the cookie session as expected **(app.sid=123)**

When going to x.example.com, the same session is being sent to the server **(app.sid=123)**, but the session is not extracted from the redis store. Instead, it overrides '123' key in redis with an empty state, and now the state is also gone for dashboard.example.com

Any help / directions would be appreciated!
Thanks!